# How to fake cpu architecture in docker container?

Tags: centos, docker, centos5

When I create 32 bit CentOS 5 docker image I would like cpu architecture to be reported as i386/i686 there (installer which tested in this container check architecture and installs 64 bit binaries instead of 32 bit).
I set yum variables and created uname wrapper, so yum and checks in bash scripts are working:

```
bash-3.2# uname -a
Linux c538cf9bf508 3.13.0-24-generic #47-Ubuntu SMP Fri May 2 23:30:00 UTC 2014 i686 i686 i386 GNU/Linux
bash-3.2# uname -p -m -i
i686 i686 i386
bash-3.2# cat /etc/yum/vars/arch && cat /etc/yum/vars/basearch
i686
i386
```

But python still reports 64 bit

```
bash-3.2# python
Python 2.4.3 (#1, Jan  9 2013, 06:49:54) 
[GCC 4.1.2 20080704 (Red Hat 4.1.2-54)] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import os, platform
>>> platform.machine()
'x86_64'
>>> os.uname()
('Linux', 'c538cf9bf508', '3.13.0-24-generic', '#47-Ubuntu SMP Fri May 2 23:30:00 UTC 2014', 'x86_64')
```

Is there a way to fake cpu architecture everywhere?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I hope there's a more elegant way to do this, but here's what I do: preface any command you want to run with `linux32`.  For example:

```
$ docker run -t -i toopher/centos-i386:centos6 /bin/bash
[root@b027ad7830ac /]# uname -a
Linux b027ad7830ac 3.16.4-tinycore64 #1 SMP Thu Oct 23 16:14:24 UTC 2014 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
[root@b027ad7830ac /]# linux32 uname -a
Linux b027ad7830ac 3.16.4-tinycore64 #1 SMP Thu Oct 23 16:14:24 UTC 2014 i686 i686 i386 GNU/Linux
[root@b027ad7830ac /]# linux32 python
Python 2.6.6 (r266:84292, Jan 22 2014, 09:37:14) 
[GCC 4.4.7 20120313 (Red Hat 4.4.7-4)] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import os, platform
>>> platform.machine()
'i686'
>>> os.uname()
('Linux', 'b027ad7830ac', '3.16.4-tinycore64', '#1 SMP Thu Oct 23 16:14:24 UTC 2014', 'i686')
```

Alternatively you can use `linux32` in the invocation of `docker run`:

```
$ docker run -t -i toopher/centos-i386:centos6 /usr/bin/linux32 /bin/bash
[root@0f289d955fe1 /]# uname -a
Linux 0f289d955fe1 3.16.4-tinycore64 #1 SMP Thu Oct 23 16:14:24 UTC 2014 i686 i686 i386 GNU/Linux
[root@0f289d955fe1 /]# python
Python 2.6.6 (r266:84292, Jan 22 2014, 09:37:14) 
[GCC 4.4.7 20120313 (Red Hat 4.4.7-4)] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import os, platform
>>> platform.machine()
'i686'
>>> os.uname()
('Linux', '0f289d955fe1', '3.16.4-tinycore64', '#1 SMP Thu Oct 23 16:14:24 UTC 2014', 'i686')
```

Or even better, use a docker image (or build your own) that configures `linux32` as it's `ENTRYPOINT`, such as:

```
FROM toopher/centos-i386:centos6
ENTRYPOINT ["linux32"]
```

Comment: I was trying to use it before, but found only 64bit package, now I found it in package setarch and it is working fine, thanks. I'm setting it as entrypoint and it should resolve my problem.

Comment: Great point - I've updated the answer to include the `ENTRYPOINT` suggestion.

Comment: Just a note: I have pull-requested to toopher/centos-i386:centos6, so it now works fine out of the box: https://github.com/toopher/toopher-docker/pull/1

Answer (score 3):

Evan's answer does work but you still need to prefix almost every `RUN` line in your `Dockerfile` with `linux32`.  To avoid this I added the following near the top of my `Dockerfile`:

```
RUN rm /bin/sh && \
  echo -e '#!/bin/bash\n/usr/bin/linux32 -- /bin/bash "$@"' > /bin/sh && \
  chmod +x /bin/sh
```

`/bin/sh` is normally a symbolic link to `/bin/bash`.  This replaces the symbolic link with the following script:

```
#!/bin/bash
/usr/bin/linux32 -- /bin/bash "$@"
```

Which makes every invocation of `RUN` in your `Dockerfile` run under `linux32`.  Unless you use the `RUN ["command"...]` format which bypasses calling `/bin/sh`.  In which case, you will have to add the `linux32` prefix manually.

Comment: I believe the cleaner way to accomplish this would be to set the SHELL directive near the top of the your Dockerfile, eg:
`SHELL ["/usr/bin/linux32", "/bin/sh", "-c"]`

Answer (score 1):

For CentOS, you only need to modify the following files:

```
+RUN echo "i686" > /etc/yum/vars/arch && \
+    echo "i386" > /etc/yum/vars/basearch
```

(just like I did in [the pull-request to toopher/centos-i386:centos6](https://github.com/toopher/toopher-docker/pull/1))

```
$ docker run -it --rm toopher/centos-i386:centos6 sh
sh-4.1# python
Python 2.6.6 (r266:84292, Jan 22 2014, 09:37:14)
[GCC 4.4.7 20120313 (Red Hat 4.4.7-4)] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import os
>>> os.uname()
('Linux', 'dc8d1dc46702', '3.16.0-4-amd64', '#1 SMP Debian 3.16.7-ckt11-1+deb8u6 (2015-11-09)', 'i686')
```

Comment: This is awesome! Thanks.