# Set Docker default architecture (armel/armhf/armv71) for Raspberry Pi

Tags: python, docker, arm, raspbian, raspberry-pi3

I am trying to build and run cross-platform Docker spec for Python application. As suggested, my Dockerfile has "python" as an OS image:

```
FROM python:2.7
```

which supposed to resolve to an appropriate image for a current platform. 
The issue is - on Raspberry it resolves to "armel" architecture which is lowest common denominator to all versions. I would like it to resolve to "armhf" or "armv71" for the sake of performance - especially having in mind that Docker providing official images for these platforms.

(Update) Workaround - before building containers, pull armhf/python:2.7 image from Docker repository and tag it as python:2.7

Comment: So basically, when building on Raspberry it resolves to "armel" architecture? And you want it to resolve to "armhf" or "armv71"? This sounds like something you would configure on the instance of Docker that is running/building the image. You could force it with something like this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26490935/how-to-fake-cpu-architecture-in-docker-container but I might be barking up the wrong tree here.

Comment: Similar issue here: https://github.com/docker/docker.github.io/issues/3835

Comment: @dkanejs Altering Dockerfile ("FROM armhf/python:2.7") will indeed solve the problem - but this is something I am trying to avoid. Probably I haven't formulate it correctly - I want to build a cross-platform container spec, not a binary image.

Comment: I think I understand, what architecture does `docker system info` on the Pi say? I thought maybe your image was resolving to the `armel` architecture because the Pi has `armel` set as its architecture instead of `armv71` or something.

Comment: @dkanejs Seems that the issue is related to an official Python image, not to a Docker service. Kernel reports "armv71" but dpkg/apt "architecture" is set to "armel" - so at least there is a workaround (replace architecture via Dockerfile RUN command). Will contact a maintainer next week to see if there is better solution