# Creating container image of old Centos

Tags: docker

I need to create Centos 6.9 32bit system image. I found [manual](https://docs.docker.com/develop/develop-images/baseimages/#create-a-full-image-using-tar) how to do that which contains link to [script](https://github.com/moby/moby/blob/master/contrib/mkimage-yum.sh).

I suppose for this reason I need to run `Centos 6.9 32bit`, install docker in it and then run script.

Trying to install docker in Centos 6.9 and. Found that it is not possible to install on this system according to requarements in manual:

```
OS requirements
To install Docker CE, you need a maintained version of CentOS 7
```

How to create container for of old `Centos 6.9` ?

Comment: Would the i386/centos:6 image work for your use case or do actually need it to run on a 32-bit kernel? If so, have you tried to build a 32-bit docker daemon as described below?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is already an official CentOS 6 32-bit image in [Docker Hub](https://hub.docker.com/r/i386/centos/), so you might not need to create your own. It can run on an x64 host.

There is no `centos:6.9` tag but a quick test of the `centos:6` tag shows that it is 6.9 anyway:

```
$ docker pull i386/centos:6
  6: Pulling from i386/centos
  6fe27d5f397b: Pull complete 
  Digest: sha256:af47b24bee01b29f3c86e484b716651f89c93d8ca73d88c1a74019c691e0d1e2
  Status: Downloaded newer image for i386/centos:6

$ docker run -it i386/centos:6 bash
  [root@508467e5637e /]# cat /etc/redhat-release 
  CentOS release 6.9 (Final)
```

### Update

I see from your [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49334209/getting-32-bit-centos-docker-image) that you had already found the official 32-bit CentOS 6 image but want it to run on a 32-bit host kernel.

According to the [docker installation prerequisites](https://docs.docker.com/install/linux/docker-ce/binaries/), it needs a 64-bit host. Docker does have 32-bit packages but they only contain the docker client and not the daemon.

If you want to run a 32-bit version of the docker-daemon, you could try following this blog post which describes how to [build it from source](https://www.nirmata.com/2016/02/09/docker-daemon-for-x32-architectures/).

Comment: Following the same procedure now leads to install CentOS 6.10 release.
Any way to get CentOS official 6.9 32-bit image?

Comment: @Parth Doesn't look like there is a tag for it any more but you can pull it using the sha256 digest above - lucky I put that in there! ;-) `docker pull i386/centos@sha256:af47b24bee01b29f3c86e484b716651f89c93d8ca73d88c1a74019c691e0d1e2`. Then tag the downloaded image: `docker tag c56776bb6939 i386/centos:6.9`. Run the image (`docker run -it i386/centos:6.9 bash`) then cat the /etc/redhat-release file and it should give the same output as above.